# iframes and reloading

Tags: iframe

I recently seen a flash game application that posted a score to a db and there was an iframe that reloaded when the score was updated it was simple but i cant seem to find anything on google, and the page was taken down- how car i achieve this myself?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 60000); // Reload after 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they used jQuery/javascript  and called the reload function from within the flash

http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/how-to-refreshreload-page-using-jquery.html

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate an iFrame with JavaScript, I think something similar could be acheved with AS3 too.
http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Working-with-IFRAME-in-JavaScript/1/